# XBox 360 Wiresless controller play Flight Simulator X on Steam

Tags: pc, controllers, flight-simulator-x

I picked up an XBox 360 wireless controller for windows and I'm having trouble getting it picked up in microsoft flight simulator x for steam.

Worth noting I'm running Windows Server 2k8 - so I copied joy.cpl from a windows 7 box and I can get the calibrate panel open (A) and calibrate, but the controller doesn't show up in the "controller type" menu of fsx (B)

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/10854/142047/0yqXrdmeawCynp0/upload.png

Answer (score 1):

Have you successfully used this controller (and all its buttons) in another game? If so, we can determine the Windows settings are probably correct. If not, I would suggest you download and install the 'latest' drivers for the controller dongle at:

https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/nl-nl/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows

After installation go to your computers devices and remove the driver for the dongle then manually select the new driver.

I did all this to get the dongle + multiple 360 controllers working on my windows 8.1 system.

According to pcgamingwiki (http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Microsoft_Flight_Simulator_X) there should be support for your controller.